# Using Config.skip with a React-Apollo Query

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm having some trouble making use of the ***Config.skip*** property inside of my *graphql()* wrapper.

The intent is for the query to be fired with an argument of *currentGoalID*, only after a user has selected an item from the drop-down (passing the associated currentGoalID) , and the (Redux) state has been updated with a value for *currentGoalID*.

Otherwise, I expect (as per Apollo documentation) that:

> *... your child component doesn’t get a data prop at all, and the options or props methods are not called*.

In this case though, it seems that my skip property is being ignored based upon the absence of a value for currentGoalID, and the option is being called because the webpack compiler/linter throws on line 51, `props is not defined`...

I successfully console.log the value of currentGoalID without the graphql() 
wrapper.  Any idea why *config.skip* isn't working? Also wish to be advised on the proper use of *this* in graphql() function call. I've excluded it here, but am unsure of the context, thanks.

```
class CurrentGoal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render (){
    console.log(this.props.currentGoalID);
    return( <p>Current Goal: {null}</p>
)
    }
  }

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    return {
        currentGoal: state.goals.currentGoal,
        currentGoalID: state.goals.currentGoalID,
        currentGoalSteps: state.goals.currentGoalSteps
    }
}

const FetchGoalDocByID = gql `
query root($varID:String) {
  goalDocsByID(id:$varID) {
    goal
  }
}`;

const CurrentGoalWithState = connect(mapStateToProps)(CurrentGoal);

const CurrentGoalWithData = graphql(FetchGoalDocByID, {
 skip: (props) => !props.currentGoalID,
 options: {variables: {varID: props.currentGoalID}}
})(CurrentGoalWithState);

// export default CurrentGoalWithState
export default CurrentGoalWithData
```

Comment: Can you add a console.log inside your skip function to print the props?

Comment: Sure, I'll try. I'm usually unconfident about the ability to console.log within an object...

Comment: Thank you, @stubailo.  I gave it  skip: (props) => console.log(props.currentGoalID). And 'failed to compile', again, on the options line below

Comment: Indeed props is undefined. Shouldn't that condition it's-self be enough to call skip()?

Comment: Yeah I think you had an exception in your `skip` function and we just don't handle that. Mind opening an issue on `react-apollo`?

Comment: Will do, thank you.

Comment: @Zach_is_my_name have you opened the issue? can I have a track of it? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Pass Props From Redux Store into Apollo GraphQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915868/how-to-pass-props-from-redux-store-into-apollo-graphql-query)

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47943253/763231

`connect` must be the last decorator executed, **after** `graphql`, in order for `graphql` to include the props from Redux.