# How To Pass Props From Redux Store into Apollo GraphQL Query

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm just getting going with Apollo GraphQL on a simple React Native app and am really impressed by what it can do. But I'm not quite wrapping my head around how it integrates with the Redux store. Essentially, I need to pass some user input from my `searchReducer` into my GraphQL query. I thought I could simply pass the connected component to my GraphQL query and supply a variable, but it's not finding the `prop` `searchInput`. Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Repository from './Repository';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const query = gql`
    query repositoryOwner($login: String!) {
        repositoryOwner(login: $login) {
            url,
            avatarUrl(size: 100),
            repositories(first: 5) {
                nodes {
                    name,
                    description
                }
            }
        }
    }`;

class RepositoryList extends Component {

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return <Repository name={item.name} description={item.description} />;
    }

    render() {

        const { repositoryOwner } = this.props.data;
        const data = repositoryOwner ? repositoryOwner.repositories.nodes : [];

        return (
            <FlatList data={data}
                renderItem={(repo) => this.renderItem(repo)} keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

    return {
        search: state.searchReducer
    };
};

const withStore = connect(mapStateToProps)(RepositoryList);

export default graphql(query, {
    options: ({ search: { searchInput }}) => ({ variables: { login: searchInput }})
})(withStore);
```

I thought that by passing the `connect`ed React component, it would find the `search` `prop` specified by `mapStateToProps`. However, it gives:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating _ref3.search.searchInput).

So obviously it's not finding that `prop`. My question is, what is the idiomatic way to use `props` from the Redux store as variables in an Apollo GraphQL connected component?

Comment: Use graphql first on the component and then connect. This way connects props will be injected into the query wrapper.

Comment: That seemed to work! Thanks for the help. My one concern is that I attempted to use Apollo's `compose` API: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/setup.html#compose and it didn't seem to take the `props`. Kept complaining about not being able to call a class as a function. Any thoughts on using `compose` properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an answer that goes more into detail and is useful for other users:

To use props from the redux `connect` higher order component make sure that the function is applied last. This can be done in your example by

```
const WithGraphql = graphql(/* ... */)(RepositoryList);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WithGraphql);
```

Alternatively you can use `compose` from *redux* or *react-apollo*.
Compose applies functions from last to first. For two arguments compose can be written as the following:

```
compose = (f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args))
```

Make sure to list connect first here and then graphql. This creates a new function that you then have to apply to your component `RepositoryList`:

```
export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  graphql(/* ... */),
)(RepositoryList);
```

Comment: Right on @Herku. Worked like a charm for me. I think I was passing `connect` second into my `compose` and it was messing things up. Thanks for taking the time to write a thoughtful answer!

Comment: Thank you for the workaround! This does seem like a bug though, so I've also opened an issue [here](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/350#issuecomment-375354403).